# How to filter the products that are only in Stock? (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter the products that are only inStock: true, I do not know how to insert it on this code:

[image]

The products are showing even the inStock is false. Here is how my products look like:

[image]

Comment: Please include code in a codeblock rather than an image. And it doesn't look like you're actually filtering on the value of `inStock` anywhere in your code.

Comment: To expand on Henry Woody's comment, please read "[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the items depending on the value of `inStock` you should use `.filter()` like so:

```
products.filter(product => product.inStock === true)
```

Here `product` represents an element of `products`, which in your case is an object, and like any object you can access the properties inside using the dot accessor '.'

Comment: `=== true` can be eliminated.

Comment: @gurkensaas It's there just to make it easier to understand for the user that asked the question